# What better I use for Negative Binomial Regression with library(MASS) glm(family=negative.binomial) or glm.nb?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression, overdispersion

Hay, im a newbie and still need more learn. I have several question, I'm trying to create a negative binomial regression model using the R and library(MASS). But i'm still confusing what sould I use glm (Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7, family=negative.binomial(theta), data, maxit) or  glm.nb.

What is the difference between those two functions?
[some one said if we don’t know overdispersion parameter we can't use glm(), so glm.nb() is the option; and other person said, in glm.nb() theta is assumed theta=1].

Anotherhand, i am still confused about theta, in some discussion forum it said theta is an overdispersion parameter, but others said theta is a shape parameter for distribution and overdispersion is the same as k, as discussed in The R Book (Crawley 2007).

I have read a tutorial to negative binomial regression with R (but still for me not look that corect). In that tutorial, suggest to trial and error what theta value until Residual deviance equal to degrees of freedom with glm (Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7, family=negative.binomial(theta), data, maxit)

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The negative binomial model is a generalized linear model only when the overdispersion parameter [theta](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10419/what-is-theta-in-a-negative-binomial-regression-fitted-with-r) is known. In applications, we don't know it, and it needs to be estimated along with the other parameters in the model.

`glm(., family = negative.binomial(theta))` requires you to have a value `theta` that you can supply. `glm.nb()` fits the traditional negative binomial model where theta is estimated. The latter is the on you want; never use the former.

Theta is not assumed to be 1 in `glm.nb()`, but it is initialized with an arbitrary value because the way model fitting works with `glm.nb()` is that an initial guess of the parameter estimates is updated until convergence. The initial value can be supplied to `init.theta`, but there is no reason to do this in most cases.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it was very helpful