# Theta in a negative binomial random generator

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, count-data

The `R` function below draws random `counts` from a `negative binomial` distribution. The `n` is the `number` of trips a person made into a forest.  The `mu` is the `mean` number of birds seen per trip.  I understand that `size` is a `dispersion parameter` for the `negative binomial`.  So, if `20` trips were taken, a `mean` of `mu = 0.8` birds were seen per trip, and the `dispersion parameter = m/(theta-1)` then the `number` of birds seen on each trip is `0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`:

```
set.seed(17)
N <- 20
m <- 0.8
theta <- 22
rnbinom(n = N, mu = m, size = m/(theta-1))
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

My question is where does the equation `m/(theta-1)` come from?  Where can I read more about it?  I have looked at a dozen websites focused on the `negative binomial` without finding this parameterization.  Nor have I found it yet in: 1.) `Wikipedia`, 2.) the documentation for an `R` package focused on statistical distributions, 3.) a book on statistical distributions, 4.) the documentation for the `R` function `rnbinom` or 5.) any of several journal articles on the `negative binomial distribution`.

Comment: How about [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10419/what-is-theta-in-a-negative-binomial-regression-fitted-with-r) ?

Comment: @frank Thank you.  I saw that before I posted my question.  I do not see the equation `m/(theta-1)` there.  I am asking specifically about the equation `m/(theta-1)`.  Not necessarily about `theta`.

Comment: If you don't have any reference for the expression `m/(theta-1)`, how did you come up with it? What is `theta` in your case?

Comment: I obtained the code in an email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started writing a comment in an attempt to clarify a jumble of different notations but it rapidly grew overlong. I'll do my best to untangle things a bit, at least.

There's several parameterizations in various places in the literature.

I wanted to use $\theta$ to represent what `rnbinom` calls `size` (to match Venables and Ripley and simplify my discussion), but you're using $\theta$ for something else so that's out. Let's call it $\kappa$.

The parameterization used in `rnbinom` has the density as:

$$f(x;p,\kappa)=\frac{\Gamma(x+\kappa)}{\Gamma(\kappa)\, x!}\, p^\kappa\, (1-p)^x,\: x=0,1,2,...,\:  0<p\leq 1,\,\kappa>0$$

In the documentation of `rnbinom`, $\kappa$ is called `size` (`n` when they write the density). In the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) on the negative binomial, it's called $r$ (it uses the same definition up to simply using a different symbol for that parameter).

The parameterization used in MASS (the book and the package that comes with R) is
in terms of $\mu= \kappa (1-p)/p$ and $\kappa$ [1] (though they use $\theta$ where I have $\kappa$).:

$$f(x;\mu,\kappa)=\frac{\Gamma(y+\kappa)}{\Gamma(\kappa)\, y!}\, \frac{\kappa^\kappa \mu^y}{(\mu+\kappa)^{y+\kappa}},\: y=0,1,2,...,\:  \mu,\kappa>0$$

The (excellent) book by Dunn and Smyth uses a different parameterization again ($\mu$ and $\psi=1/\kappa$).

This $\kappa$ (aka `size`, $r$) is indeed sometimes called a dispersion parameter by some authors, though it's not a dispersion in the sense of the *exponential dispersion family*; with fixed $\kappa$ I believe that the GLM's dispersion parameter is $1$.

It is, however, related to the sense in which a negative binomial model might be called *overdispersed* relative to the Poisson, in that $\kappa\to \infty$ would correspond to the limiting Poisson case and any positive value of $\kappa$ would be overdispersed, with smaller $\kappa$ being overdispersed to a greater extent; since the variance is $\mu+\mu^2/\kappa$.

If you want to have a more natural "overdispersion" parameter, Dunn and Smyth's [2] parameterization in terms of $\psi=1/\kappa$ makes more sense (larger $\psi$ means $Var(Y)/E(Y)$ increases, though the excess is related to $\mu$).

---

So now we come to the question of *what does your $\theta$ represent*?

Note that `m/size` in `rnbinom` or $\mu/\kappa$ is $\theta-1$ in your question, which in Wikipedia's parameterization is $\frac{1-p}{p} = \frac{1}{p} - 1$. So your $\theta$ appears to be $1/p$ (per both Wikipedia and `rnbinom`).

Where that parameterization (in terms of your $\theta=p^{-1}$) comes from, I cannot say, unfortunately. Where did you see it?

---

[1]: Venables and Ripley, (2002), *Modern Applied Statistics with S* (4th ed) [Sec 7.4]

[2]: Dunn and Smyth, (2018), *Generalized Linear Models With Examples in R* [Sec 10.5.2]

(Note to self: I should dig out the book by de Jong and Heller and check their parameterization, but if memory serves I think it used essentially the same form as MASS does.)

Comment: Thank you.  Someone sent the code to me in an email.  I can ask him about it next week with a link to this post if nobody here recognizes a source for `m/(theta-1)` before then.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have figured out where the `size = m/(theta-1)` came from for the `negative binomial distribution` parameterization in my original post.  The `size` parameter apparently can be estimated using the `method-of-moments` as:

```
size <- mean(counts) / (var(counts) / mean(counts) - 1)
```

when `counts` come from:

```
counts <- rnbinom(n = N, mu = m, size = m/(theta-1))
```

So, `theta` in this parameterization seems to be defined as:

```
var(counts) / mean(counts)
```

where `m = mean(counts)`.

I found the `method-of-moments` equation for `size` in notes from one of `Ben Bolker`'s labs at this link:

[https://math.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/lab6.html](https://math.mcmaster.ca/%7Ebolker/emdbook/lab6.html)